# Allow Multiple optional parameter in @escaping in swift

Tags: swift, escaping, closures

I have this method :

```
    func getdata(someString: String, onComplete: @escaping ((_ someArrayData: [String], _ error: Error?) -> Void)) {
            var result: [BanPhone] = []
            // Some Actions
            if(someaction is successful) 
           { 
                                onComplete(result)
    
           }
           else {
                                onComplete(result, Error)
            }
}
```

Error is optional i want to pass this parameter only when i get error. else i wanted to send back result.
How can i do that over here

Comment: Whats the question ?

Comment: Seems like a use case for [`Result`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result)

Comment: I agree with Sweeper. But, the code you have works now if you just put `onComplete(result, nil)`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question, you call it with a result when successful, passing `nil` for the error parameter, e.g. in success scenario:

```
onComplete(result, nil)
```

And if there was some error, you’d call it supplying the error code, but no value:

```
onComplete(nil, error)
```

---

Nowadays, we would generally use [`Result`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) type. See https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/result/ for practical discussion.

We favor `Result` over the “two optional parameters” pattern because it makes it explicit to the caller that either it will be successful with a value or a failure with an error, one or the other, but not both.

```
func fetchData(with someString: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[String], Error>) -> Void)) {
    ...

    doingSomethingAsynchronous {
        ...

        // if failed
    
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }
    
        // if successful
    
        completion(.success(value))
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```swift
fetchData(with: string) { result in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

    case .success(let value):
        // do something with `value`
    }
}
```

Now, this is how the two optional parameter pattern tends to work in practice (it is one or the other), but `Result` formalizes the contract, saves you from unwrapping optionals, etc.